# Mouse Hover event in ComboViewer

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Can we use `ComboViewer` to listen mouse hover event? I want to basically display the hover value in tool tip for the list in a combo box

Example:

I have a combo list with values "a", "b" and "c". When I move the mouse over "b" I need to display "b" in tool tip.

```
viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
viewer.setInput({"a", "b", "c"})
viewer.getCombo().addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener(){
 public void mouseMove(MouseEvent event){

  // here i need a logic to read identify on which value the mouse is over.

 }
});
```

Comment: How about `viewer.getCombo().addMouseTrackListener(...)`?

Comment: This helps! But how can I identify on which item the mouse is currently pointing to

Comment: You will probably have to iterate and compare the `y` position to the mouse event.

Comment: I have edited my question with an example. With y position from the mouse event, please explain how to identify the list item.

Comment: Hmmm, seems like the `Combo` doesn't fire mouse events for the drop-down part...